# What "putting Akka on the boot class" means?

Tags: java, scala, classloader, akka

I am reading akka specification paragraph [A Word About ClassLoaders](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/general/configuration.html).

> In several places of the configuration file it is possible to specify the fully-qualified class name of something to be instantiated by Akka. This is done using Java reflection, which in turn uses a ClassLoader. Getting the right one in challenging environments like application containers or OSGi bundles is not always trivial, the current approach of Akka is that each ActorSystem implementation stores the current thread’s context class loader (if available, otherwise just its own loader as in this.getClass.getClassLoader) and uses that for all
>   reflective accesses. This implies that **putting Akka on the boot class path** will yield NullPointerException from strange places: this is simply not supported.

What this exatclty means? Does this mean that using classloaders in akka configuration is not safe? And when and why I should configure custome classloader?

Answer (score 0):

[Boot class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) is the class path used by the bootstrap class loader and contains the core jar files of JVM: `rt.jar`, `core.jar`, `server.jar`, etc. As the documentation says,

> It is very unlikely that you will need to redefine the bootstrap class path.

This doesn't mean anything about custom class loaders.